# Batch to copy files from text document

Tags: powershell, batch-file, copy, xcopy, robocopy

I have found a number of posts relating to the following but have not yet made my way to a solution!

I have a filelist.txt file contaning a list of files:

```
C:\test1\sample1.txt
C:\test2\sample2.txt
C:\test3\folder1\sample3.txt
C:\test3\folder1\sample4.txt
C:\test3\folder1\folder2\sample5.txt
```

I want to use a batch file with copy, xcopy or robocopy to read the exact files and copy them to a specified directory along with the folders ie. resulting:

```
C:\copy_folder\test1\sample1.txt
C:\copy_folder\test2\sample2.txt
C:\copy_folder\test3\folder1\sample3.txt
C:\copy_folder\test3\folder1\sample4.txt
C:\copy_folder\test3\folder1\folder2\sample5.txt
```

In the source directories a there may be other files, but these should not be coppied, only those found in the filelist.txt file. So a replica filestructure is made but without unspecified files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %x in (filelist.txt) do @echo %~dx "%~px" "%~nxx"` could be a starting point. Read _entire_ `for /?` (up to _substitution of FOR variable_)

Comment: Your result example is wrong. The "sample2.txt" file should be `C:\copy_folder\test2\sample2.txt`, and the same point apply to the rest of files, **OR** the first file is wrong and should be `C:\copy_folder\sample1.txt`. Which one of these _different_ results is what you want?

Comment: Apologies Aacini, the first is the correct way round. I have amended the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a pure `PowerShell` method you could use the following code:

```
$destination = "C:\copy_folder"
$textFileWithPaths = "C:\filelist.txt"

Get-Content $textFileWithPaths | % {
    # Create the destination folder path
    $NewFolder = Split-Path (Join-Path $destination $_) -Parent | Split-Path -NoQualifier`

    # Check if the path exsists - create if it doesn't exsist
    If(!(Test-Path $NewFolder)){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewFolder -Force
    }
    # Copy the file to new location
    Copy-Item $_ $NewFolder -Force
}
```

This code will take each file path from a given text, and then create the folder tree of the file (all but the drive letter). Then make a copy of the file to the new location.

Comment: Thanks Chard, I actually just got round to pretty much the same method with PowerShell - thanks for your input!